# max number checkbox columns datagridview

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

I am working in VB.NET and have a datagridview with multiple columns, the first being a checkboxcolumn.  I want to add the functionality to restrict the amount of rows the user can select.  For example, I may have 10 rows of entries in the datagridview but want to only allow for 5 checkboxes to be checked.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the readonly property of datagridview to prevent the edit.and use a for loop to limit which all rows to be disabled.

```
for i=5 to datagridview1.rows.count-1

dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[columnindex].ReadOnly = true;

next
```

Specify the index of column to disable at column index.this code will disable editing of 6th to last row of datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

You can Maintain States of `CheckBoxes` in `ViewState` and Then Check Length of Array List which Gives You No of Items Checked

```
Dim CheckBoxArray As ArrayList

If ViewState("CheckBoxArray") IsNot Nothing Then

   CheckBoxArray = DirectCast(ViewState("CheckBoxArray"), ArrayList)

Else

   CheckBoxArray = New ArrayList()

End If
```

Add or Remove items From `ViewState`

```
 If chkAll.Checked Then

   If CheckBoxArray.IndexOf(checkAllIndex) = -1 Then

      CheckBoxArray.Add(checkAllIndex)

   End If

Else

   If CheckBoxArray.IndexOf(checkAllIndex) <> -1 Then

      CheckBoxArray.Remove(checkAllIndex)

      CheckAllWasChecked = True

   End If

End If
```